# Diagram explanation

Tags: identification, components, symbol

[image]

Can someone explain what the components in this picture are? I recognize the 50 Ω resistors, and are those switches, shielded wires, and amps?!?

does the arrow on the switch indicate the direction of the current?

edit: realized the triangle is the common aka ground

Comment: Not amps, but ground (and inputs).

Comment: The arrowhead on the switches are the moving contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplified schematics relate to Keysight multiport coaxial switches using magnetic latching relays.

Model 87104 is for switching 1 of 4 ports to a common port and Model 87106 for 1 of 6 ports.

Coaxial connectors and cables are used.

Letter A / B / C, in the model number, indicates operating frequency dc to 4 GHz, dc to 20 GHz and dc to 26.5 GHz respectively.

The unswitched ports get terminated through 50 Ω resistors.

The relays get latched / unlatched by the drive circuitry, when the corresponding signal input pins are made 'high' or 'low'.

Answer (score 3):

Those are [multiport coaxial switches](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/product/87104B/87104b-multiport-coaxial-switch-dc-to-20-ghz-sp4t.html).

The circle around the wire indicates coaxial connectors with the outer conductor grounded.

C is the common connection, it will connect one of the inputs to common at a time, the rest will be connected to 50\$\Omega\$ terminating resistors.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown Figure 1 from a Keysight manual for electromechanical microwave SP4T or Single Pole 4 Throw switches.

I expect these are more sturdy and reliable selectors than constantly switching semi-rigid coaxial cables that perform better than flexible cables above 1GHz.

What you may not know is:

- microwave connector threads can shift insertion loss plots by 0.1 dB or more so the connections must be torqued with a calibrated tool and this performance degrades after 100 cycles or so. Thus very high reliable switches with very low microwave loss would be good for production line testing.
- Microwave flex coax. is far more sensitive to handling degradation.  You may experienced issues like this on HDMI cables.